# Internal databinding callbacks are null when returning to fragment (onResume)

Tags: android, android-fragments, mvvm, data-binding

We have a setup where we use a `BaseObservable` `ViewModel` that is set as a variable on the databinding layer trough xml.

We have a situation where we have a `Fragment` that displays a list of items. This fragment starts an `Activity` trough `startActivityForResult` to edit this list. When coming back we update the `ViewModel` in `onResume` (this works), but the databinding internal callbacks aren't triggered. The bindings we had set in our xml (something like `@{viewModel.isLoading}`) aren't executed anymore, even though `notifyPropertyChanged` is called.

When debugging we've found that the binding object contains an extensive list of `WeakReference$OnPropertyChangedCallback`s before we leave the fragment, these are the internal callbacks used by the databinding framework. Upon returning to the Fragment these have all been disposed of, which kind of makes sense since they're a weak reference.

Is this supposed to happen? If so, how do I make sure the callbacks get rebound to my binding object?

For reference a small psuedo code-ish sample:

In fragment `onCreate`:

```
mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(TGMyNewsViewModel.class);
```

In the fragment `onCreateView`:

```
mBinding = FragmentMyNewsBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
mBinding.setViewModel(mViewModel);
```

In `onActivityResult`, when we've verified something has changed:

```
mViewModel.startViewModel();
```

This triggers a reload, this reload is being done successfully.

Then the actual layout is not updated with property changes in the ViewModel.

Comment: The WeakReferences should only be disposed of when the Views are collected. That shouldn't happen when the Fragment's View is in the hierarchy. But even if you're dropping the Fragment and recreating it, your use of `ViewModelProvider` should hook everything up again properly in the `onCreateView()`. The only thing I can think could be a problem is if you're using retained instance fragments. Are you?

Comment: @GeorgeMount Sorry for the late reply on this. So it turned out I was deleting the weak referenced propertychanged callbacks myself. Thanks for the answer though!